# Resolving Maven circular dependencies between test, testhelper, and project-under-test

Tags: unit-testing, maven, maven-2, dependencies, circular-dependency

my set up is this. I have project `A`, and a test project depending on `A`:

```
A <- A_t
```

I also have other projects depending on `A` (and their tests):

```
A <- B <- B_t
```

To simplify some of the testing I introduce a new library helping test stuff based on `A`:

```
A <- Atesthelper
```

So `A_t` (and `B_t`) will depend on this test helper, like this:

```
A <- A_t
^    |
|    v
Atesthelper
```

However when I create Maven projects (pom.xml) it seems the usual thing is to bundle both the project and the test of that project in the same pom.xml. And I create a new pom.xml for the `Atesthelper`

So now it becomes:

```
(A <- A_t)
  ^    |
  |    v
Atesthelper
```

Which is a circular dependency. Is it possible in the pom.xml to somehow specify that `Atesthelper` is only a dependency of the test build target, and not the `A` module in itself?

So the build order should be: A, Atesthelper, A_t. I.e. A and A_t which are specified in the same pom, should not be build at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would really help if you pasted the relevant excerpts from the poms of the projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you need to solve is the dependency from *Atesthelper* to *A*, then everything else will work fine: *A* depends on *Atesthelper*, *B* depends on *Atesthelper* and both *A* and *B* will contain both sources and tests. *Atesthelper* will be included with scope *test* in both *A* and *B*. That's your target state.

How do you get there? You need to extract the items that *Atesthelper* is depending on into a separate projects. Typically, these are interfaces or other common functionality, which should be put into a separate project anyway - let's call it *ACommon*. So your target layout should look like this:

```
ACommon <- Atesthelper
       ^    ^
       |   /
         A (and also B)
```

What kind of functionality is *Atesthelper* depending on in *A*? Can you move it to a separate project (*ACommon*)?

Comment: `Atesthelper` has to depend on A, as it is effectively a helper to test stuff in `A` and therefore depends on many of the data-only objects in `A` and interacts with objects in `A`. So I don't think that is the correct dependency to break. I was hoping for an answer regarding how to configure maven to build `A` and `A_t` separately.

Comment: This sounds like a design issue to me. You're trying to fight the way Maven handles projects and dependencies: One project, one artifact. You might be able to tweak this somehow to your needs, but it will give you more trouble in the long run. Keep it simple and stick to way Maven does things. BTW: Uncle Bob has described something similar many years ago - the Dependency Inversion Principle, worth a read: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf

Comment: So Maven dictates one project one artifact. Thus, there should be one project (aka pom.xml) for A and another project for A_t. This will solve the issue, but I thought that you "normally" put the project and it's test in the same pom.xml. I understand (and use) DI, but which dependency would you inject in this situation?

Comment: The article is about dependency *inversion*, not *injection*. Two different things. Both implementation and test should be in the same project, that's the standard setup. My recommendation was to break the dependency between your project A and the test helper classes.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand you right, your primary goal is to reuse test classes. A_t and Atesthelper are not Maven projects, they are tests.

Make Maven to create a jar from your src/test/java. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html

After build of A you will get A.jar and A-tests.jar. A-tests.jar will include Atesthelper and A_t.

Set dependency of B to A-tests.jar (`<type>test-jar</type>)`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste your POMs and I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I'll try to help you how I've got it. This is quite common case that usually should be solved like this:

Your `Atesthelper` artifact (probably `jar` packaging), that supports testing, should have all its testing-related stuff in the `src/main` directory (so classes in `src/main/java`, resources in `src/main/resources`, etc.), not `src/test`! All its dependencies, so `A`, but also stuff like JUnit, EasyMock (all stuff that testing-support classes need) you declare with `compile` scope, which is the default one of course. Don't use `test` scope here! Finally, in `A` and `B` artifacts, declare `Atesthelper` as dependency of `test` scope.

That solution works great for me for many years. It is clean and straigt about dependencies (they're transitive in contrast to `<type>test-jar</type>`-based solution if you know what I mean). Anyway, just use it. You'll be happy ;).

Comment: Does not address the issue of the circular dependency.

Comment: I think that the circular dependency problem will disappear by using this solution. As I said, I've never had any problem with that. IMHO it should work really well.

Comment: I guess this could work if you first build `A` and `B` with [skipping the tests](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#skip-test), then build `Atesthelper`, and then build `A` and `B` again with tests.

Comment: @MichalKalinowski: This is (kind of) what I have tried, I was thinking that using scope correctly should be the solution. However, I cannot get around that `A` and `A_t` should not be build right after each other, `A` first, then `Atesthelper` and then `A_t`, and I don't know if maven can do this when `A` and `A_t` are specified in the same `pom.xml`?

Comment: Yeah, this cannot work like this. Probably you should user @nwinkler solution or maybe rethink things. The responsibility of `Atesthelper` helper is somehow not clear for me, to be honest. If it shoule be some kind of common testing support module, it should depend on common classes module, not some specific stuff, because then you have specific test helper.

Comment: that is exactly the problem, you write a Module A and a Module B. B depends on A, so far no problem. now you want to write a test for the Module A: AT. AT now obviously depends on A, but can depend on B as well. for those 3 projects, there is no problem at all. but the maven structure encurages to put everything from AT into the test folders of A, which then causes the problem that A (because of AT) depends on B, and B depends on A.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to solve this issue is to keep the projects separated. There are frameworks like Maven that encourage you to put Classes and Test Classes into one single project. Eclipse PlugIn projects for example have separate test projects. Making `A_t` a sub-project of `A` sounds like the best solution, since you can reuse whatever dependencies you want in that test project without worrying about the impact on `A`.

This scenario will arise more often and you might not want to bother your project design with dependencies of tests. Those tests should be independent and not influence your class design.